# Is there a cyclic subgroup of $A_8$ of order $10$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I'm trying to check if there is a cyclic subgroup of $A_8$ of order $10$.

I believe that it does not have one. I think that we can prove it by showing that it can't get build.

The problem is more technical. I think that I understand the solution but I have never written a prove similar to this one so I don't understand how properly to prove it. Is it possible how to explain the proof? Would be glad to get some guidelines.

Comment: There are elements of order $10$ in $S_8$. Prove they are all odd permutations.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have an element of order $10$ in $A_8$. Note that every element in $A_8\leqslant S_8$ is a product of disjoint cycles. At the same time, the order of each product of disjoint cycles equals the least common multiple of each cycle. Now since $8<10$ and $10=2\times 5$, the only possibility for the element of order $10$ in $A_8$ is $$(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7),\ a_i's\ \text{are distinct elements in}\ \{1,2,...,8\}. $$
However, this will always be an odd permutation, since $$(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7)=(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)(a_3a_5)(a_3a_6)(a_3a_7)$$ has $5$ transpositions which is obviously odd. Contradicting the fact that $A_8$ consists of even permutations. Hence we conclude that there is no element of order $10$ in $A_8$ and it follows that there is no cyclic subgroup of order $10$ in $A_8$.